Raspberry Pico not recognized in lsusb, no serial port created
I am trying to get my computer (fedora) to recognize my Raspberry Pi Pico. The Pico works — it is capable of running simple programs that can blink the LED / output digital signals, but I can't get the serial port to work. Here is the full code I am running to test it:
#include <stdio.h>
#include "pico/stdlib.h"
int main()
{
    stdio_init_all();
    
    while (1)
    {
        printf("Hello World From Pi Pico USB CDC\n");
        sleep_ms(100);

    }
}

When plugged in, lsusb shows nothing connected. No /dev/tty file is created. dmesg shows no logs when the Pico is plugged in; literally nothing happens.

You will normally create the device /dev/ttyACM0 on plugging your Pico in by USB. If you then look, you will see device node is owned by root dialout, that's user root and group dialout. For that to work, your user must be a member of the dialout group. To add your user to the dialout group simply use # gpasswd -a youruser dialout (the # just indicates a root-prompt, or you can use sudo as well. After you add yourself to dialout, /dev/ttyACM0 (or perhaps /dev/ttyACM1) will be created and you can communicate with the Pico.

For example, on my laptop (openSUSE), when I connect the pico, I get ls -al /dev/ttyACM0 with output of crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 166, 0 Sep 29 04:15 /dev/ttyACM0.

What's the CMake here? If you don't setup the stdio as "USB", you won't get a USB serial port. Double check with https://github.com/raspberrypi/pico-examples/blob/sdk-2.0.0/hello_world/usb/CMakeLists.txt. Also, the Pico's USB port should reappear if you unplug the USB cable, then hold down the BOOT(SEL) button, then plug the USB cable back in (with the button still being pressed). The USB bootloader code is unkaputtbar.
